# How to use scala.xml.transform.RuleTransformer in UDF? (gives scala.MatchError: scala.xml.Node)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am attempting to register a Spark UDF in order to help me transform a XML string from a table but am getting the following exception. May I know what am I missing? I am using Scala 2.12.10 and Spark 2.4.4.

```
package org.mt.experiments

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

import scala.xml.transform.{RewriteRule, RuleTransformer}
import scala.xml.{Elem, Node, NodeSeq}

object Launcher2 {

  case class Student(name: String, books: String)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .master("local[*]")
      .enableHiveSupport
      .getOrCreate

    import spark.implicits._

    spark.udf.register("cleanXML", (xmlDoc: Node) => {
      new RuleTransformer(new RewriteRule {
        override def transform(node: Node): NodeSeq = node match {
          case e: Elem if e.label == "author" => NodeSeq.Empty
          case node => node
        }
      }).transform(xmlDoc)
    })

    val andy = Student(
      name = "Andy",
      books = "<books><book><<title>Functional Programming in Scala</title><author>Paul Chiusano and Runar Bjarnason</author><year>2014-12-26</year></book><book><title>Real and Complex Analysis</title><author>Walter Rudin</author><year>2015-05-19</year></book></books>"
    )
    val studentDF = Seq(andy).toDF()
    studentDF.createOrReplaceTempView("studentDetails")
    val tokDF = spark.sql("SELECT name, cleanXML(books) as books FROM studentDetails")
    tokDF.show(false)
  }
}
```

ERROR

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: scala.xml.Node (of class scala.reflect.internal.Types$ClassNoArgsTypeRef)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.$anonfun$schemaFor$1(ScalaReflection.scala:760)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection.cleanUpReflectionObjects$(ScalaReflection.scala:925)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:740)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.$anonfun$schemaFor$1(ScalaReflection.scala:761)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection.cleanUpReflectionObjects$(ScalaReflection.scala:925)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:740)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:736)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration.register(UDFRegistration.scala:192)
    at org.mt.experiments.Launcher2$.main(Launcher2.scala:22)
    at org.mt.experiments.Launcher2.main(Launcher2.scala)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: scala.xml.Node (of class scala.reflect.internal.Types$ClassNoArgsTypeRef)

The error says that `scala.xml.Node` is not supported as a type of a UDF function as an input or output.

According to the scaladoc of [RuleTransformer.transform](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.x/index.html#scala.xml.transform.RuleTransformer):

> transform(...): Seq[Node]

So the following code that you want to register as the `cleanXML` user-defined function returns an unsupported type and hence the exception.

```
(xmlDoc: Node) => {
      new RuleTransformer(new RewriteRule {
        override def transform(node: Node): NodeSeq = node match {
          case e: Elem if e.label == "author" => NodeSeq.Empty
          case node => node
        }
      }).transform(xmlDoc)
    }
```

You could simply `.headOption.map(_.toString).getOrElse(...)` or similar to work it around.